# Not able to install CacheCow.Server 0.5.0-alpha

Tags: caching

CacheCow.Server 0.5.0-alpha (Pre-release) has dependency on CacheCow.Common (≥ 0.5.0) but yet this version is not available on NuGet.

While I'm installing CacheCow.Server 0.5.0, it's failing due to the dependency on Cache.Common 0.5.0

Does anyone has idea when this will be available on NuGet ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved.
Please refer following URL for the solution steps -

http://byterot.blogspot.in/2013/12/cachecow-0.5.0-alpha-new-feature-breaking-changes-asp-net-web-api.html